# How to write */ in javadoc without ending the comment

Tags: javadoc

I want to write a sed expression (sed -e 's/  */ /g') in one of my Javadocs.

Problem is */ ends the javadoc section.
I couldn't find any way to tell the compiler (or Eclipse) that this doesn't end the comment.

Is it even possible or should I try to change the documentation to go around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write &#47 instead of /, so you could write it like this:

```
/**
 * your description here *&#47
 */
```

and it will be displayed as "your description here */"

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't sed let you change the delims like `sed -e 's| *| |g'` ?

Comment: Yep, I didn't know that! Thanks! I'm just gonna upvote you though, since the other answer gives a broader solution.